# What Post/Put has to do with Insert/Update of record

Tags: web-services, rest, jersey, httprequest, restful-url

May be I am talking too theoretical but I am not getting fundamentally clear on Put/Post requests relation to update/insert of record.
I have used Post request number of times and I have implemented a lengthy business logic in my resource/implementation files that do Updates & Inserts both in the database during processing the request.
I am sure the Update/Insert notion for Put/Post is not in context with database but then where does it is making difference.

This is my 1st question on SO, I hope it will make less destruction.

Comment: You're correct that PUT/POST have nothing to do with the database queries. Technically there is nothing that ties these concepts together. For example, there is nothing stopping you from using a POST request to handle code that DELETES something; the problem with that though is it could be confusing to other developers working with your code. POST/PUT and INSERT/UPDATE have semantic meanings that make sense as a convention, and so it is considered good API design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially speaking, the actions you are talking about is actually related to the RESTful design principle. it has nothing to do with database, they don't have to really touch your database, only a describe of what you are doing with your web resources. They are meaningless if your URL naming is not apply with the RESTful convention. 
FYI. http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gijqy.html